# How can I get histogram number with pairs by using python code?

Tags: python-2.7

I want to take hist no with pairs by using python code like when i put input 11 2 34 21 the output should be like that 11(1) 2(1) 34(1) 21(1)

Answer (score 1):

First, let's create a list of numbers (I have added some repeats to make it more interesting):

```
>>> v = ( 11, 2, 34, 21, 2, 2 )
```

Next, let's create a Counter instance:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> ctr = Counter(v)
```

Now, let's get the counts that you wanted:

```
>>> dict(ctr)
{2: 3, 11: 1, 34: 1, 21: 1}
```

If you prefer the parenthesized format that you show in the question, then we need to do some formatting:

```
>>> ' '.join('{}({})'.format(x, ctr[x]) for x in ctr)
'2(3) 11(1) 34(1) 21(1)'
```

You can read more about the Counter class in the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Answer (score 0):

The code below is admittedly less efficient than the solution proposed by @John1024. I'm posting it in the hope that it could provide some additional insight into how to create a histogram.

We start by generating some random integers:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.seed(123)    # to ensure reproducibility of results
>>> nums = [random.randint(10, 15) for i in range(12)]
>>> nums
[10, 10, 12, 10, 15, 10, 13, 11, 15, 10, 12, 12]
```

Then we count the occurrences using the [count()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=count#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) method for sequence types and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression):

```
>>> counts = dict((n, nums.count(n)) for n in set(nums))
```

And after some formatting (I'm using Python 2.7), this is what we get:

```
>>> ' '.join(['%g (%d)' % (n, counts[n]) for n in sorted(counts)])
'10 (5) 11 (1) 12 (3) 13 (1) 15 (2)'
```