# how can I match specific letter and count its frequency?

Tags: python, counting

Using regex, I wanna count the specific letter. I made a match object like below. but don't know how to count its frequency. Most of counting examples were for words so I could not find good reference for it.

```
f = open("C:\Python27\test.txt")
raw_sentence = f.read
upper_sentence = raw_sentence.upper()
match = re.findall(r"A", upper_sentence)
```

Should I make some list data just like other word counting codes do?

Comment: The title is about letter and description is about word, which one is it? Having example input and expected output would be helpful too.

Comment: sorry it was letter. And the result that I want is like "A  : 3", "B : 6" like this

Comment: Possible duplicate from yesterday: [How can I get histogram number with pairs by using python code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084670/how-can-i-get-histogram-number-with-pairs-by-using-python-code/)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `str.count`:

```
raw_sentence.upper().count('A')
```

If you want counts of multiple elements, its better to use `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> s = 'abcabcsdab'
>>> import collections
>>> collections.Counter(s)
Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'd': 1, 's': 1})
```